# How to check unordered_set for overlaping?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, unordered-set

I have two unordered_sets and need to check if all the elements of the first one are also elements of the second one.

Is there a fast way to do this or should I use another container?

Comment: IIRC there's no way to get the hashed key of an element out of an `unordered_map`. Therefore, you'll have to rehash each element.

Comment: I reckon the sets aren't of same size, right? Otherwise you could use `operator==`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a loop (or a corresponding algorithm). The complexity is (approximately) linear in the size of the range to be tested.

```
template <typename UnorderedSet, typename Iterator>
bool contains_all(UnorderedSet&& set, Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    using value_type = std::iterator_traits<Iterator>>::value_type;
    return std::all_of(first, last, [&set] (const value_type& value) {
        return set.count(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: This would require C++14. Replace `auto` by `Type` to make it compile for C++11.

Comment: +1, I'd suggest renaming it to `unordered_includes` to mimic the `std::includes` that is present for ordered inputs. I'd also give it 4 iterators as parameters instead of 2 containers.

Comment: Could changing the type of one of the containers improve performance?

Comment: @TemplateRex I see how you can do that with 2 iterators + 1 container, but with 4 iterators?

Comment: @dyp oops forgot that the `count()` member was being used

Comment: I'd use an `UnorderedSet const&` as parameter type (e.g. otherwise you can't pass const lvalues).

Comment: @dyp: You can pass all kind of references, because `UnorderedSet` can be instantiated with a reference types.

Comment: Oops I keep forgetting the `const` is deduced for class types. Nevertheless, `UnorderedSet const&` can *also* take lvalues and rvalues, and expresses more clearly that the argument is not changed.